# How do I declare buttons in my fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a button in the fragment XML but can't initialize a button in the fragment class. How do I do it?

When I use the code below in my fragment class, it gives me an error.

```
public class Autoservice extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autoservice_layout, container, false);
Button clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
return v;
}
```

The button initialization gives me an error. What way should I use to declare a but within a fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Autoservice extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autoservice_layout, container, false);
Button clear = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.clear);
return v;
}
```